# How can we get specific data from JSON object in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm trying to get the user id from the following JSON response:

```
    "status": "200",
    "msg": "Login Success !!",
    "userdata": {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "Zulqarnain",
        "gender": "male",
        "dob": "1999-10-10",
        "email": "zulqarnain@gmail.com",
        
    }
}
```

I'll try to get it by writing the following code in flutter:

```
Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body);
   List<dynamic> data = map["userdata"];
   print(data[0]["id"]);
```

but it gives me the error **Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List'**, how can I solve this issue.

Comment: Are you getting only single user or multiple from JSON? Can you add JSON response, more structured way?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, this is occurring because the content in map["userdata"] is a Map<String, dynamic> and you are trying to assign it to a List.

To fix that, you can set the type of the data variable to Map<String, dynamic>
and, when trying to get the id of the data variable, you just use data["id"]. The [0] part is not necessary, since you're not trying to access a list.

```
Map<String, dynamic> data = map["userdata"];
print(data["id"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

`List<dynamic>`

to

`Map<String,dynamic>`

If you have JSON like ["foo", "bar", "baz"] you get a List, but if you have JSON like {"foo": 1, "bar": 2, "baz": 3} you get a Map<String,dynamic>.

Comment: I also wrote this line in my code, kindly review the question one more time I've edited it.

Comment: try this print(map["userdata"][0]["id"]);  or print(map["userdata"]["id"]); if only one user. may be it's helpful.